# GridLayoutManager changes to LinearLayoutManager after calling onSaveInstanceState

Tags: java, android, android-layout

In my app I am using a RecyclerView with GridLayout. I am trying to save the current item index so that it's restored correctly after rotating a device. The first thing that seems not to be working is saving the LayoutManager object as Parcelable:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.i("From onPause1", (mMoviesRecyclerView.getLayoutManager())+"");
    mLayoutManagerState = mMoviesRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();
    Log.i("From onPause2", (mLayoutManagerState)+"");
}
```

> I/From onPause1: androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager@fdb47c1

> I/From onPause2: androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$SavedState@53fe516

Does anyone have an idea why I get LinearLayoutManager$SavedState in the second logging?
Thanks in advance.

@Edit1

Those are the methods I'm using:

```
    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.i("From onPause1", (mMoviesRecyclerView.getLayoutManager())+"");
    mLayoutManagerState = (mMoviesRecyclerView.getLayoutManager()).onSaveInstanceState();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelable(LAYOUT_MANAGER_STATE, mLayoutManagerState);
    Log.i("From onSaveINstance", (mLayoutManagerState)+"");
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (savedInstanceState instanceof Bundle) {
        Log.i("From onRestoreInceState", (savedInstanceState.getParcelable(LAYOUT_MANAGER_STATE)+""));
        layoutManager = (GridLayoutManager) savedInstanceState.getParcelable(LAYOUT_MANAGER_STATE);

    }
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

I get an error after rotation:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
> androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$SavedState cannot be
> cast to androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager

Answer (score 0):

As [`GridLayoutManager`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/a910619/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.java#35) extends `LinearLayoutManager`:

```
public class GridLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
    ...
}
```

it's a trivial result that an instance of `GridLayoutManager` is a `LinearLayoutManager` too.
Since `onSaveInstanceState()` is implemented in `LinearLayoutManager` so the `SavedState` returned value is from type of `LinearLayoutManager.SavedState`.

```
private GridLayoutManager layoutManager;

@Override
public void onCreate(savedInstanceState outState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, X);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelable(LAYOUT_MANAGER_STATE, layoutManager.onSaveInstanceState());
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState instanceof Bundle) {
        layoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState.getParcelable(LAYOUT_MANAGER_STATE));
    }
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for pointing that.
However, I still get an error while casting the object to GridLayoutManager:

java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$SavedState cannot be cast to androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager

I have edited my question to provide the full code.

Comment: The returning value by `onSaveInstanceState()` is an instance of [`SaveState`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/a910619/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.java#1853) which holds the internal state of the layout manager as a parcelable. So, it could not be casted to `GridLayoutManager`.